# Number of Lattice points in the intersection between an N-Sphere and an N-Cube

Tags: geometry, algorithms, integer-lattices, spheres

I have a hyper-Cube lattice with coordinates between 0 and 10, therefore 11^N lattice points.
I take one of this point, C, and then another point P at distance D from C.
I need to know a good algorithm or even a close formula that gives me the number of lattice points that have a distance from C equal or less than D.
Since N, the dimensionality of the problem, could be of the order of the hundreds, I would prefer not to examine the distance of all 11^N points from D.

What have I done so far? Not much, to be honest.
I my mind this problem is equivalent to counting the number of lattice points in the intersection between the hyperspher centered in C passing through P and the hypercubewith side 11 and a corner in the origin.

I tried the low dimensionality approach to see if a pattern emerges but already the 1 dimensional problem has too many "IF" conditions.

Let's say I am interested in a good approximation of the result, then i could calculate the intersection of a N-Sphere and an N-Cube but it would be too imprecise for small values.

Are there some easy formulas for this kind of problem? From the other pages I find in stackechange the problem seems quite hard but maybe the box constraint, instead of being a difficulty, simplifies something

Comment: Are you aware of [The Number of Lattice Points in a *k*-dimensional Hypersphere](https://archive.org/details/numberoflatticep175mitc) by W. C. Mitchell? In two dimensions, this is very close to the [Gauss Circle Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss_circle_problem). The radius is indeed so small that analytical estimates based on hypervolume are not very useful. I would personally see if estimating it using Monte Carlo integration at integer lattice points (in entire hypercube, or just the positive quadrant from $C$), compared to slow but exact counts, yields acceptable answers.

Comment: Thank you for the interesting link. Anyways, I need an exact calculation, no estimates

Comment: We know that the hypersphere is centered on a lattice point. Have you investigated the lattice point pairwise distances in high number of dimensions? One way would be to precalculate the number of lattice points at each exact distance, and tabulate them separately, so one could sum them up to $D$. (The box constraint actually makes the problem harder.)